# Retrieve single value onWrite firebase cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How to retrieve a single  value (restaurant_token)from firebase RealTime when there is a new child added

my structure is :

-RestaurantsOrders

-- random Push key

--- restaurant token

[See screenshot for node.js firebase cloud function][1]

[See screenshot for Firebase DB reference][2]

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO. Please do not attach screenshots of your code, but copy/paste the code in the question and format it as code. This way it allows others to copy it in order to adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value): You need to do along the following lines

```
exports.sendNotif = functions.database.ref('/RestaurantOrders/{pushId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = change.after.val().restaurant_token;

      // ....

      await admin.messaging(...)...

      return null;

    });
```

---

Note the `return null;` at the end: have a look at this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details on this key point.